# Remove Mobile/Tablet Responsiveness from CSS?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I am currently working on a HTML/CSS website. The website currently has CSS in place that makes its responsive to Desktop/Mobile/Tablet. I want to remove the responsiveness and make it render the same on all devices as it does on desktop. Here is the CSS code below:

```
 /* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  RESET
------------------------------------------------------------- */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {display: block}
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
html { font-size: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
:hover, :focus, :active { outline: none; }


html, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: "Open sans", "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400; /* normal */
    color: #555; 
    font-smooth:always;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);}

body { margin: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.6; }

a { color: #0078CF; font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;  text-decoration: none;
    transition:color 0.2s ease; -moz-transition:color 0.2s ease; -webkit-transition:color 0.2s ease; -o-transition:color 0.2s ease;}

a:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: underline; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .025);} 

::-moz-selection { background: #0078CF; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #0078CF; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }    

p{margin: 0 0 1em;}
p:last-child {margin-bottom: 0;}

a:visited{opacity:0.9;}
a:active, a:focus{position:relative;top:1px;}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}
dfn{font-style:italic}
hr{display:block; height:1px; border:0; border-top:1px solid #ddd; margin:1em 0; padding:0}
pre, code, kbd, samp{font-family:monospace,monospace; _font-family:'courier new',monospace; font-size:1em}
q{quotes:none}
q:before, q:after{content:""; content:none}
blockquote { margin: 1em 1em 1em 0; padding: 1em; border-left: 1px solid #DDD; font-style: italic; color: #999;}
blockquote p {font-size: 1.1em;line-height: 2em;margin-bottom: 0;}
blockquote small {display: block;font-size: 1em;line-height: 1.6em;color: #bfbfbf; text-align: right;}
blockquote small:before {content: '\2014 \00A0';}
b, strong{font-weight:700}
small{font-size:85%; color: #999;}
sub, sup{font-size:75%; line-height:0; position:relative; vertical-align:baseline}
sup{top:-0.5em}
sub{bottom:-0.25em}
dd{margin:0 0 0 40px} dt{font-weight: 700;}
ul, ol{list-style:none; list-style-image:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
img{border:0; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; vertical-align:middle}
svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}
figure{margin:0}
form{margin:0}
fieldset{border:0; margin:0; padding:0}
label{cursor:pointer}
legend{border:0; *margin-left:-7px; padding:0;white-space: normal;}
button, input, select, textarea{font-size:100%; margin:0; vertical-align:baseline; *vertical-align:middle}
button, input{line-height:normal; *overflow:visible}
table button, table input{*overflow:auto}
button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"]{cursor:pointer; -webkit-appearance:button}
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box; box-sizing:content-box}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}
button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0; padding:0}
textarea{overflow:auto; vertical-align:top; resize:vertical}
table{border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0}
td{vertical-align:top}
.chromeframe { margin: 1em 0; background: red; color: black; padding: 1em; }



/* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  STYLES
------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* -- FORMS 
------------------------------------------------------------- */
form{margin-top: 2em;}
form li{margin-bottom: 1.5em;}
label{display: block; margin-bottom:1em; font-weight: 700;}
input, select, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    width:60%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    *behavior: url(/js/boxsizing.htc); }
textarea{padding: 1em; min-height:15em; height: auto; width: 100%; }
input, textarea {
 -moz-transition: border .25s;
 -webkit-transition: border .25s;
 -o-transition: border .25s;
 transition: border .25s;}
input:hover, textarea:hover, input:focus, textarea:focus,input:active, textarea:active { border: 1px solid #999;}
input[type="text"],textarea{cursor: text;}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] { display: inline; width:auto; height: auto; margin-right: 1em; }
input[type="checkbox"] + label, input[type="radio"] + label { display: inline;}
input[type="file"]{ border: none;}
input[type="date"]{ width: auto;}
select {height: auto;}
/* Placeholders */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #BBB;}
:-moz-placeholder {color: #BBB;}
:-ms-input-placeholder {color: #BBB;}
/* validate.js */
label.error { color: #0078CF; margin: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; }



/* -- BUTTONS 
------------------------------------------------------------- */
.button, input[type="submit"], button, .toggle-title {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    background: #efefef; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 0%, #efefef 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#efefef)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 0%,#efefef 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 0%,#efefef 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 0%,#efefef 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f6f6f6 0%,#efefef 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#efefef',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -ms-border-radius: 2px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

    -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 0.1s linear all;
    -ms-transition: 0.1s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.1s linear all;
    transition: 0.1s linear all; }
.button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, button:hover, .toggle-title:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: #BBB;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background: 0 100%;}
.button:focus, input[type="submit"]:focus, button:focus, .toggle-title:focus {
    color: #333;
    border-color: #BBB;}
.button:active, input[type="submit"]:active, button:active, .toggle-title:active {
    color: #000;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    border-color: #444;
    position: relative; top:1px;}



/* -- TYPO
------------------------------------------------------------- */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{margin:0 0 1em; font-weight: normal;}

h1 {font-size: 4.1em; 
    letter-spacing: -0.075em; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    line-height: 0.9; 
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em; 
    font-weight: normal; }
h2 { font-size: 2.5em; margin: 0 0 20px; letter-spacing: -0.05em; color: #555; line-height: 1; }
h3 { font-size: 1.75em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.5em; }
h5 { font-size: 1.17em; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; color: #555; }
h6 { font-size: 1em; margin-bottom: 2px; font-weight: 700; }

h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a{color:#333; text-decoration: none;}
h1 a:hover,h2 a:hover,h3 a:hover,h4 a:hover,h5 a:hover,h6 a:hover{color:#0078CF;text-decoration: underline;}



/* -- GRID  https://github.com/mattberridge/Proportional-Grids/
------------------------------------------------------------- */
body{width:100%;}
.container {width: 90%; margin: 5em auto; max-width: 1100px; min-width: 300px;}

.grid-wrap {
  margin-left: -3em; /* the same as your gutter */
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom:1;}
  .grid-wrap:before, .grid-wrap:after{content:""; display:table}
  .grid-wrap:after{clear:both}

.grid {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3em; /* this is your gutter between columns */
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  *behavior: url(/js/boxsizing.htc); }

.half-gutter {margin-left: -1.5em; }
  .half-gutter .grid-col {padding-left: 1.5em; }

.col-full {width: 100%; }
.col-one-half {width: 50%; }
.col-one-third {width: 33.333%; }
.col-two-thirds {width: 66.666%; }
.col-one-quarter {width: 25%; }
.col-three-quarters {width: 75%; }

.divide-top{border-top: 1px solid #ccc;padding-top: 2em;margin-top: 1.5em; }

.mright{ margin-right: 3em;}
.mleft{ margin-left: 3em;}
.mtop{ margin-top: 3em;}
.mbottom{ margin-bottom: 3em;}
.halfmright{ margin-right: 1.5em;}
.halfmleft{ margin-left: 1.5em;}
.halfmtop{ margin-top: 1.5em;}
.halfmbottom{ margin-bottom: 1.5em;}

.fright, .fleft{display:block; overflow:hidden}
.fright{float:right}
.fleft{float:left}

.alignleft{float: left;clear: left;margin: 0.38em 1.62em 0.38em 0;}
.alignright {float: right;clear: right;margin: 0.38em 0 0.38em 1.62em;}
.aligncenter {margin: 0 auto 1.62em;display: block;}



/* -- MISC
------------------------------------------------------------- */
figure { max-height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
figure figcaption { }
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
a img {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease; }
a img:hover {
    *zoom: 1;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 70);
    filter: alpha(opacity = 70);}



/* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  PAGES
------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* -- HEADER
------------------------------------------------------------- */
header#navtop { margin-bottom: 2em; clear: both; overflow: hidden; }
    header nav ul { float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 0 3em 0 2em; border-left: 1px solid #ddd; line-height: 2em; }
nav a, menu a { text-decoration: none; color: #555; }
.navactive { color: #0078CF }
.logo {margin-bottom: 1px;}
.logo:hover {background: none;}


/* -- GENERAL 
------------------------------------------------------------- */
.main > section { margin-bottom: 7em; }
.main header{ color: #555; margin-bottom: 3em; }
.main header hr{border-top-color:#999;}
.arrow:after {content:" \27F6"; /* html unicode: &#10230; */ } 
header .arrow {color: #999; font-style: italic;}
.arrow:hover {color: #0078CF; }


/* -- FOOTER
------------------------------------------------------------- */
footer  { color: #555; margin-bottom: 7em; }
footer nav ul { float: right; overflow: hidden; }
footer a {color: #999;}
footer li { float: left; margin-right: 1em; padding-right: 1em; border-right: 1px solid #DDD; font-size: 0.8em; }
footer li:last-child { margin-right: 0; padding-right: 0; border-right: none; }
.up a { display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; }


/* -- HOME-PAGE
------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Services */
.services aside { color: #999; padding-top: 1em; border-top: 1px solid #DDD;}
.services aside:after, .services h5:after { content: ""; display: block; height: 1px; width: 1em; background: #DDD; margin: 1em 0; }

/* Slider */
    /* Browser Resets */
.flex-container a:active,.flexslider a:active,.flex-container a:focus,.flexslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,.flex-control-nav,.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;} 
    /* FlexSlider Necessary Styles */ 
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative;}
.flexslider .slides > .slide {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}
.slides:after {content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;} 
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;} 
* html .slides {height: 1%;}

.slide figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto; min-height: 3em; width: 60%; padding: 1em; 
    top: 3em; right: 0; }
.slide figcaption div { text-align: right; display: block; border-right: 1px solid #DDD; padding: 0 2em 0 0; margin: auto 5em auto 0; }
.slide figcaption div p { margin: 0 }
.flex-direction-nav{ position: absolute; top: 25em; right: 1.5em; z-index: 10;}
.flex-direction-nav li {display: inline;}
.flex-prev, .flex-next{ text-decoration: none; color: #fff; margin-left: 36em;}
.flex-prev:hover, .flex-next:hover{ color: #0078CF}


/* -- WORKS / Home-page and Works-page
------------------------------------------------------------- */
.works figure > a{ 
    display: block; 
    height: 100%; width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD; padding-top: 1em; }

.works figure .zoom{ 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0; 
    background: url(../img/zoom.png) no-repeat center; 
    width: 100%; height: 100%; 
    *zoom: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 0);
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0); }

.works figure figcaption{ margin-top: 1em; padding: 0 0.5em; white-space: nowrap; }
.works figure figcaption a{line-height:2em; color: #555; font-weight: 700; }
.works figure figcaption p{ margin: 0; }

.works-page .works figure { margin-bottom: 3em;}

.main aside{margin-bottom: 3em}
.main aside menu{padding: 0 0 0 1em; line-height: 2em;}
.main aside menu a{color: #999;}
.main aside menu .buttonactive {color: #0078CF }


/* -- SUBPAGES 
------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*Separations*/
.main:not(.home-page) > section article h2 { margin-top: 1em; padding-top: 1em; border-top: 1px solid #DDD; }
.main:not(.home-page) > section article:first-child h2 { margin-top: 0;}

/* Work-page (single) */
.work-page figure {margin-bottom: 3em;}
.work-page figcaption {text-align: center; margin-top: 1em;}

/* Services-page */
.warning { 
    display: block; 
    background: #F5F5F5; 
    border: 1px solid #DDD; border-left: none; border-right: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 20px; margin: 20px 0px; }

    /* - Toggles */  
.toggle-view > li {
    margin-top: 1em;
    position: relative; }
.toggle-title {padding: 0.8em 2em;}
.toggle-title-detail {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: lowercase; }
.toggle-title:after {
    content: "\25C0";
    float: right;
    color: #999; }
.toggle-title:hover:after { color: #555 }
.tactive { background: #FFF }
.tactive:after {
    content: "\25BC";
    color: #555;}
.toggle {
    padding: 1em 2em;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden; }
.toggle > ul li { line-height: 2.5 }
.toggle > ul li:before {
    content: "\2714 ";
    color: #ddd;
    margin-right: 1em; }

    /* - Tabs */
.tabs {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd; }
.tabs li {
    display: inline-block; margin-bottom: -1px; }
.tabs li a {
    display: block; 
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 3em;
    color: #555; 
    padding: 0 2em; 
    margin: 0;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 1.1em;}
.tabs li a:hover{color: #000;}
.tabs li.active a{
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    color: #111;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px; }

.tab_container { margin-bottom: 1em; display: block; border-left: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 15px 15px 0;}
.tab_container > article { display:none; }
.tab_container > article:first-child { display: block; }



/* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  BLOG
------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Article */
.post {margin-bottom:5em}
.post .entry{margin:1.5em 0;}
.post .entry p{overflow:auto}
.post .more-link {font-weight:700; color: #0078CF;}
.post .more-link:hover {color:#333;}
.meta {font-weight: normal; color:#999; font-size:0.9em}
.meta a {color:#555; text-decoration:none;}
.meta a:hover {color:#0078CF; text-decoration:underline;}

/* Sidebar */
.blog-sidebar {color: #999;}
.blog-sidebar h2{margin-bottom:1em; font-size:2em; color:#666;}
.blog-sidebar .widget{padding-bottom:2em;border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;margin-bottom: 2em;}
.blog-sidebar .widget:last-child{border-bottom: none;}
.blog-sidebar a {font-weight: normal; color:inherit;text-decoration: none; }
.blog-sidebar a:hover{color:#333;}
.blog-sidebar li{padding-left: 1em; margin-bottom: 0.5em;  white-space: nowrap ; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 95%; overflow: hidden; display: block;} 
.blog-sidebar li a:before {content: ">"; padding-right: 1em;} 
.blog-sidebar input {width: 90%; padding-right: 0;}

/* Pagination */
ul.page-numbers{float: right;overflow:hidden; display:block;}
.page-numbers li {float:left;}
.page-numbers li a{ display:block;padding:1em;text-decoration:none; color:#777;}
.page-numbers li a:hover{ color:#444;}
.page-numbers li .current{color: #0078CF;}

/* Comments*/
.section-comment header{overflow: hidden; clear: both;}
.comments, .leavecomment {margin-top: 3em;}
.comment{margin-bottom: 2em;}
.comment p{font-size: 0.9em; color: #777;}
.comment h6{margin-bottom: 0.5em;}
.comment form ul li { margin-bottom: 2em }



/* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  MISC
------------------------------------------------------------- */

.ir{display:block; border:0; text-indent:-999em; overflow:hidden; background-color:transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; text-align:left; direction:ltr; *line-height: 0;}
.ir br{display:none}
.hidden{display:none !important; visibility:hidden}



/* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  IE Fix
------------------------------------------------------------- */
.lt-ie9 .works figure a, .lt-ie9 .works figure a img { filter:inherit} 
/* jquery filter opacity issue IE8 */

.lt-ie9 .container {min-width: 780px;}
.lt-ie8 .container {width: 960px;}
.lt-ie8 .grid-wrap {margin-left: 0; }
.lt-ie8 .grid {padding: 0;margin-left: 5%; }
  .lt-ie8 .grid:first-child {margin-left: 0; }

.lt-ie8 .col-full {width: 99.95%; }
.lt-ie8 .col-full + .grid {margin-left: 0; }
.lt-ie8 .col-one-half {width: 47.45%; }
.lt-ie8 .col-one-third {width: 29.55%; }
.lt-ie8 .col-two-thirds {width: 64.95%; }
.lt-ie8 .col-one-quarter {width: 19.95%; }
.lt-ie8 .col-three-quarters {width: 74.95%; }



/* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  MEDIA QUERIES
------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* -- Media query 1 (mq1)
------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 60em) { /* 13 / 780 */
    .mq1-col-full {width: 100%; }
    .mq1-col-one-half {width: 50%; }
    .mq1-col-one-third {width: 33.333%; }
    .mq1-col-two-thirds {width: 66.666%; }
    .mq1-col-one-quarter {width: 25%; }
    .mq1-col-three-quarters {width: 75%; }
    /**/
    h1{font-size: 3.1em;}
    .slide figcaption{ width: 80%;}
    footer li { float: left; margin-right: 0.5em; padding-right: 0.5em; border-right: 1px solid #DDD;} 
}

/* -- Media query 2 (mq2)
------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 48em) { /* 13 / 624 */
    .mq2-col-full {width: 100%;}
    .mq2-col-one-half {width: 50%; }
    .mq2-col-one-third { width: 33.333%; }
    .mq2-col-two-thirds {width: 66.666%; }
    .mq2-col-one-quarter {width: 25%; }
    .mq2-col-three-quarters {width: 75%; }
    /**/
    header nav { width: 100%; }
    header nav ul {  padding: 0 ; border-left:none; line-height: 2em; }
    header nav ul li { float: left;  padding: 0 1em ; border-left:1px solid #ddd; }
    .slider { margin-top: 3em; }
}

/* -- Media query 3 (mq3)
------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 30em) { /* 13 / 390 */
    .mq3-col-full { width: 100%; }
    .mq3-col-one-half { width: 50%; }
    .mq3-col-one-third { width: 33.333%; }
    .mq3-col-two-thirds { width: 66.666%; }
    .mq3-col-one-quarter { width: 25%; }
    .mq3-col-three-quarters { width: 75%; } 
    .mq3-none {display: none;}
    /**/
    header nav ul li { padding: 0 0.5em ; }
    footer li { float: none; margin-right: 0em; padding-right: 0em; border-right: none; line-height: 2em;}
    .services article { margin-top: 3em;} .services article:first-of-type { margin-top: 0;} 
}

/* -- PRINT STYLES 
------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media print{ 
    *{background:transparent !important; color:black !important; text-shadow:none !important; filter:none !important; -ms-filter:none !important}
    abbr[title]:after{content:"("attr(title) ")"}
    pre, blockquote{page-break-inside:avoid}
    thead{display:table-header-group}
    tr, img{page-break-inside:avoid}
    img{max-width:100% !important}
    p, h2, h3{orphans:3; widows:3}
    h2, h3{page-break-after:avoid} 
}



/* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  END
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

*/

Answer (score 2):

Websites like yours are made responsive through Media Queries, that check the width of the browser which in turn renders different sections of CSS.

To remove all responsiveness on your site all you need to do is delete the Media Queries CSS from the bottom of your stylesheet.

So, delete everything below here: (Keep the media query for print but get rid of everything else.)

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------
======  MEDIA QUERIES
------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: Just seen a couple of other people have said the same thing. 

IN addition to my answer, you will also need to change .container to a fixed width instead of 100%.

Comment: @user3082829 If UNB's answer solved your problem then should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the  tag of your index.html (or whatever your entry point is (header.php, etc)) for a line which start with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=....">
```

...and replace the content part with this: width=1024, or whatever width you wish to have. After that, also remove media queries from the css. Now it's more likely it will render the same on mobile and desktop, although there is no guarantee for it.

Answer (score 0):

Give `.container` a fixed width as a starting point:

```
.container {
    width: 1100px;
}
```

you might also have to remove any `@media` queries relating to `device-width`

impossible to say for sure without seeing any HTMl or a test [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)